# Jquery onclick toggleClass - three clicks required instead of two

Tags: jquery

I need a cell to have three colors : first loaded by the script, second ny clicking on the cell and third by clicking on one more time. And if I click again I get the first color back.

I wrote this :

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border='2' cellpadding='20' align='center'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="switch">1</td>
        <td class="switch">2</td>
        <td class="switch">3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('\.switch').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight2');
        })
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('switch');
        })
    })
</script>
<style>
    .highlight {
        background-color: #ffff00;
    }
    .highlight2 {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
</body>
```

You can see how it works : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yr2hx096/)

My problem is that the first two clicks work fine (the color change) but the third is useless and the fourth work as the third should (get the color back to the beginning).

I need to have only three clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your problem, but here is something to start with:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var i = 0;
        $('.combi').on('click', function () {
          i += 1;
          if (i == 1) {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
          } else if (i == 2) {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight2');
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass();
            i = 0;
          }
        })
    })
```

```css
    .highlight {
      background-color: #ffff00;
    }

    .highlight2 {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table border='2' cellpadding='5' align='center'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="combi">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="combi">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="combi">15</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: It works but only with one cell, if I have many when I click on one the others will be affected and that is not what I need

Comment: @RomainCharles fixed. Check it now

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see that each cell is still not independant of the others. If I click on one to have yellow, when I click on another one it will be immediatly red and not yellow first